# setText jolts TextButton at inital position for a microsecond or two while movement is happening

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have an actor and I'm moving it by using moveTo(destinationx, destinationy, time).

The problem is that the actor is a TextButton and I need to change the text while the movement is happening and this poses a serious problem. It seems setText calls invalidate and invalidateHierarchy so when the method is called the position of the TextButton is reset to the initial position for a while so that the movement proceeds with a jolt (jump) of the text button position (position set at initialization  - .center()).

All the dynamics of my actor movements are running as planned as long as I don't modify the text while Actions.moveTo is still running.  If I do modify it then I see a jolt of the text at the moment I call setText.

How can I solve this pb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem by placing a Button in a Table and using moveTo actions on the Button. The problem is that when a widget belongs to a Table, the Table is responsible for controlling the widget's position and size, so actions that affect the position will not work correctly.

If you are moving a widget around the screen to arbitrary positions, it doesn't make sense for you to keep it in a static Table anyway. If you add the Button directly to the stage, the problem goes away.

However, I discovered another problem. If the Button doesn't have a Table parent, it doesn't update its own size correctly when its text changes.

I found a solution. Place the Button in a Container and add the Container to the Stage. Use your MoveToActions on the Container that wraps the Button, not the Button itself.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by using another method: I made the TextButton , and the Table containing it , invisible (alpha=0) , then I changed the text of the button in the next frame , and finally I made them visible in another frame.  The jolt appears no more. But , i guess, your method is much more simple.